# E-mail validation in php?

Tags: php, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP email validation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146331/php-email-validation-function)
>   [Is there a php library for email address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

I have a contact form on my site but I need a e-mail validation and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm looking at the "Related" links on the side and I'm seeing at *least* half a dozen relevant questions...

Comment: Type `php regex email` in Google. You'll get hundrets of results.

Comment: Validating emails with regex is often a bad thing; the majority of the ones you'd find from google I can break with valid e-mail addresses.

Comment: omg, he gets an upvote for this question? oO

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = "someone@example.com";

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "E-mail is not valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "E-mail is valid";
  }
```

This is probably the simplest method. The example I pasted above is from http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp and complete documentation on using filter_var is available at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1):

my old good friend [Google](http://tinyurl.com/yezbkdc) have me some interesting links:

http://www.spoono.com/php/tutorials/tutorial.php?id=41

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_email_validation-ajax.php

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Email-Address-Verification-with-PHP/1/