# How to check whether a email is valid or not in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP email validation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146331/php-email-validation-function)

How to check whether a email is valid or not in PHP?

Comment: Read the FAQ and search next time.  This has been answered hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 0):

You can only *really* check if an email address is valid by actually sending an email to it and checking for the return code from the SMTP server.

Comment: How to check return code from the SMTP server.

Comment: By not using `mail()` but one of the many send-mail-via-smtp classes available on the net. PEAR probably has a nice one.

Comment: Okay ThiefMaster thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain. You might have a huuuuuge regex to validate the syntax of an entered email address, but you cannot know if the address actually exists. With a properly configured smtp however, it will reject your attempt to send the email if the address is invalid.

Comment: While I'm not the downvoter, I expect it's because the SMTP code is going to be useless.  Most modern SMTP servers will initially accept mail and later send a bounce to prevent spammers from easily fishing for valid accounts.  Sending an email and having the user take an action specified in the mail is pretty much the only effective way to determine if the mail is *valid*.  That is, you can have a well-formed email address that's totally bogus.

Comment: thank u, I wanna to check whether email adders is exits or not, not a validation.

Comment: @Charles: I don't think so. What you mean might be graylisting where the first email is rejected with a *temporary* error code. If you get a *permanent* error code, you know the address is invalid. Sending bounces is actually a very bad thing as it often results in backscatter spam.

Answer (score 0):

GO to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

I use a PHP function on my site that checks for all those parameters.